# How to define Laravel Eloquent relationships via a intermediate table

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have three tables that look like this:

Users

- id
- name

Things

- id
- name

ThingsAssigned

- id
- user_id
- thing_id

I want to know how to set up my model relationships and how to write a query where I can pass user_id and get back this structure (will be sent as JSON):

```
"things": [
  { 
   "name":"thing1"
  },
  {
   "name":"thing2"
  }
]
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

For many to many tables, the naming of the pivot table has to be alphabetical and singular. So the correct name for the table is `thing_user`. There from it is pretty straight forward.

For your `User.php` model.

```
class User {
    public function things(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Thing::class);
    }
}
```

For the `Thing.php` model.

```
class Thing {
    public function users(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Relations in `Laravel` is about consistently follow the naming conventions and you have less problems.

To access things, you can do it like so.

```
$user->things;
```

To include things with the users you can do.

```
User::with('things')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've set up what has been suggested by @mrhn, you can use it in the following way:

```
public function randomFunction() {
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    return $user->things();
}
```